# Laravel sometimes validation on arrays

Tags: laravel, validation

Suppose we have the following form data:

```
{age: 15, father: "John Doe"}
```

We want to have some complex logic behind validating the `father` field based on other data for the same item (for this example, we want to validate that father has at least 5 characters when age < 18).

This could be done like that:

```
Standard validation rules: ['age': 'required|integer']

$validator->sometimes('father', 'required|min:5', function($data) {
    return $data['age'] < 18;
});
```

Now, we want to have the same kind of thing with a list of items. So now, we have the following form data:

```
[
  {age: 25, },
  {age: 15, father: "John Doe"},
  {age: 40, },
]
```

Common validation rule now looks like that:

```
['items.*.age': 'required|integer']
```

My issue is now to easily express the `sometimes` rule for each item's `father` field which will depend on the item's `age` field.

```
$validator->sometimes('items.*.father', 'required|min:5', function($data) {
    // Does not work anymore: return $data['age'] < 18;
    // Any way to know which item we are dealing with here?
});
```

One way I could think of is to loop over the items in a validator `after` callback. But that does not seem very elegant :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Couldn't get `sometimes()` to work in a way you need. `sometimes()` doesn't "loop" over array items, it gets called a single time.

I came up with an alternative approach, which isn't perfect, but maybe you'll find it useful.

```
/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function rules()
{
    Validator::extend('father_required_if_child', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {

        $childValidator = Validator::make($value, [
            'age' => 'required|integer'
        ]);

        $childValidator->sometimes('father', 'required|min:5', function($data) {
            return is_numeric($data['age']) && $data['age'] < 18;
        });

        if (!$childValidator->passes()) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;

        // Issue: since we are returning a single boolean for three/four validation rules, the error message might
        // be too generic.

        // We could also ditch $childValidator and use basic PHP logic instead.
    });

    return [
        'items.*' => 'father_required_if_child'
    ];
}
```

Curious to learn how this could be improved.

Answer (score 1):

The shortest approach I could get to work is this:

```
"items" => "required|array",
"items.*.age" => "required|integer",
"items.*.father" => "required_if:object.*.age,".implode(",",range(0,18))."|min:5"
```

Anytime a father is needed for that person, it should be having at least 5 characters. 
A father is needed when the person's age is below 18.

`required_if` works with multiple equations separated with commas. Therefore I wrote `0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18` as `implode(',',range(0,18))` to get that part.

The test setup I've used:

**Controller** (used HomeController)

```
function posttest(Request $request) {
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        "object" => "required|array",
        "object.*.age" => "required|integer",
        "object.*.father" => "required_if:object.*.age,".implode(",",range(0,18))."|min:5"
    ]);

    if($validator->fails()){
        dd($validator->errors());
    }
}
```

**View** (test.blade.php)

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<form action="{{URL::to("/posttest")}}" method="POST">
@csrf
<input type="number" name="object[0][age]" value="12">
<input type="text" name="object[0][father]" value="John">
<input type="number" name="object[1][age]" value="15">
<input type="text" name="object[1][father]" value="John Doe">
<input type="number" name="object[2][age]" value="17">
<input type="submit" value="gönder">
</form>
@endsection
```

**Routes**

```
Route::view("/test", "test");
Route::post('/posttest', "HomeController@posttest");
```

Comment: Clever workaround, but the condition may be more complicated than the one in our example. +1 though :)

Answer (score 0):

I make it happen using the value of the second parameter of the callback function of the sometimes method of the Validator class. Here is how I have done this using laravel 8.

```
$validator->sometimes('father', 'required|min:5', function($data,$instance) {
    return $instance['age'] < 18;
});
```